# Predicting a negative binomial model to a raster with an offset term

Tags: r, raster, predict

I'm trying to predict a negative binomial model to a stack of rasters using the `predict` function in the `raster` package. I need to include an offset term to normalize my count variable. I have tried unsuccessfully to get this to work using a method where the offset term is included in the model like this:

```
condor.glm <- glm.nb(y_count ~ logsafefood + logpigharvest +
                       logintdist + houseden + pubforest + pubrange + 
                       privforest + privrange + offset(log(offset)), 
                     data=merge.Hex, control=glm.control(maxit=1000))

predict(rasStack2, condor.glm, filename="cencal_predictlow_model15.img", 
        overwrite=TRUE, type="response", progress="text",na.rm=TRUE)
```

R throws this error:

```
Error in log(offset) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

If I pass `offset` as an argument instead:

```
condor.glm <- glm.nb(y_count ~ logsafefood + logpigharvest + 
                       logintdist + houseden + pubforest + pubrange + 
                       privforest + privrange, 
                     offset=log(offset), 
                     data=merge.Hex, control=glm.control(maxit=1000))

predict(rasStack2, condor.glm, filename="cencal_predictlow_model15.img",  
        overwrite=TRUE, type="response", progress="text",na.rm=TRUE)
```

R creates the prediction surfaces but the values are all equal.

Any suggestions for how to do this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for your question?

Comment: Please include some sample data with your question to make it easier to help. Also, the more minimal the example the better. Use only columns necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does this return: `str(offset)`?

Comment: > str(merge.Hex$offset)
 num [1:287] 1807 1807 1807 1807 1807 ...

Comment: Here is a copy of my sample data for the input model:

Comment: I am fairly certain that the source of the error is from stats::predict.glm and not raster::predict. Can you please test this by back predicting to the x matrix used in the model? In using raster predict you are calling two predict functions. The raster predict is a wrapper for whatever model you pass it. Because of this you must make sure that your prediction call for the model is working before calling raster::predict. If this is the case please edit your answer to remove the raster part as it is convolving the problem. BTW, are your offset values unique length(unique(merge.Hex$offset)) ?

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I will try back predicting. To answer your question, my offset value is not unique to each sample unit, as I am trying to adjust the y_count in each sample unit of my dataset (row) to the total number of GPS locations (in the example above, I'm using offset = log(1807)). Perhaps I'm not understanding the offset term correctly?

Comment: So, I tried back predicting the model to the spatial polygon data frame (x matrix) that I used to create the model and predict worked without errors and produced the result that I was expecting.

Comment: Holly, if you want to add data (it would help), [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35660447/edit) and add it there, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to the raster::predict function but rather your data. If you back predict the data you will see that it results in uniform values.

The issue is that you have a column "offset" named the same as a function "stats::offset. If you simply rename the "offset" column the model call for both your syntax `+ log(offsets)` or  `offset = log(offsets)` works.

To get the raster::predict function to work you will either have to fiddle with the “const” argument or create a constant raster, that can be added to your raster stack, with a uniform value of log(1807), which would be the easiest approach.